# Regex: Identify words that contain 'ing'

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm dealing with a sentence where I need to find the 'verb' of the sentence; that is to identify the words ending with 'ing'. How do I use regex to do this folks?

> He is watching a movie
>
> VERB: watch**ing**

Comment: Did you research this?

Comment: This method will, of course, neither find all verbs nor just find verbs.

Comment: The Fantastic Four asked The Thing to smash the scaffolding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Regex.Match(@"(?i)\w+ing(\W|$)")
```

Should do the trick, I assume you want to identify words like waTchIng as well, (?i) will instruct the regex engine to ignore case.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you want something like this,

```
@"\b\w+?ing\b"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without Regex:

```
string sentence="He is watching a movie";
var verbs= sentence.Split(' ').Where(x=> x.EndsWith("ing"));
```

Comment: Critical case: "The bus is leaving."